# Copy canvas to graphics object in p5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I've not been able to find a reference or figure this out, but I was curious if there is a way to take the current state of the drawn canvas in p5.js and save it to a graphics object.

Basically, I do a lot of pre-drawing in the `setup` function and would like to take a snapshot of that to be used as the background within the `draw` function.

I realize I could probably add an extra layer of complexity to my `setup` drawing by adding extra graphics objects, however it would just be much easier to get the current state into a new object/image (I have a decently complex chain of graphics objects as is that are being dropped onto the main canvas).

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if anybody pops in with an easy to use function, but I ended up copying the raw pixel array to a backup and then re-wrote it each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [`copy()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/copy) function. It can be used to copy regions of pixels within and between the canvas, `p5.Graphics` objects, and `p5.Image` objects. One thing to be aware of when copying from the main canvas to a `p5.Image` is that the main canvas has a pixel density that depends on the display (i.e. a density of 2 for high DPI displays), but `p5.Image` objects do not have a density. So for high DPI displays your `p5.Image` object needs to be oversized. For this reason it is better to use a `p5.Graphics` in my opinion. Here's a trivial example:

```js
let buffer;

function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(100);
  
  buffer = createGraphics(width, height);
  
  let saveButton = createButton("save");
  saveButton.position(20, 20);
  saveButton.mouseClicked(() => {
    // Copy from canvas into buffer
    buffer.copy(
      // source
      canvas,
      // source x, y, w, h
      0, 0, width, height,
      // destination x, y, w, h
      0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height)
  });
  
  let restoreButton = createButton("restore");
  restoreButton.position(80, 20);
  restoreButton.mouseClicked(() => {
    // Copy from buffer into the canvas
    copy(buffer, 0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height, 0, 0, width, height);
  });
}

function draw() {
  circle(mouseX, mouseY, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah, great!  i kept futzing with the copy function and for some reason couldn't get it to work.  this is a great example.

Comment: So, if I copy from a graphics instance to another or to the main canvas, should I still worry about the pixel density?

Comment: Correct. By default your main canvas should have the same pixel density as any p5.Graphics buffers instantiated with createGraphics. so you should not have to worry about pixel density.